# Searching keyword in objects

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list of objects each with a first name and last name. Im trying to make a keyword search function for both their names, so my logic is if i concatenate their first and last names, then check if the sum of both names contains the keyword, return the object as a string. I'm trying to write it as a lambda expression but I'm just not getting it. The function returns nothing every time. Im completely new to lambdas so the this simple task is quite difficult for me. When i read my code below.. i see this: Each element concatenate their names, then filter by seeing if the string contains the keyword, then convert the stream to a list objects, then convert objects to a string, then return the string. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
public String generateUserByKeyword2(String keyword){
 return  users.stream()
         .map(x-> x.getFirstName() + x.getLastName().toLowerCase())
         .filter(x -> x.contains(keyword.toLowerCase()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
         .toString();
}
```

Comment: What is the exact return type you want? Is it a `String` or a `List<String>`? If it is a `String` what represents that? You can alternatively post imperative code so that it helps people to understand the context well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search by firstname, it's not being lower-cased, the correct line should be:

```
     .map(x-> (x.getFirstName() + x.getLastName()).toLowerCase())
```

(note the additional parenthesis or you can achieve the same by calling `toLowerCase()` on both)

Anyway, the result will return the mangled concatenated names. If you want to return list of original objects, you would have to join the `map` lambda and `filter` lambda together:

```
     .filter(x-> (x.getFirstName() + x.getLastName()).toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Also, you can optimize a bit by calling `toLowerCase()` only once in advance.